# Save generated Soap XML in database when sending request to remote WS

Tags: java, web-services, soap, wsdl, jax-ws

I'm using CXF to generate classes from WSDL in order for me to consume webservice. I need to save the requests if they fail and I'd like to save the SOAP xml that is sent, together with the exceptino error in my database.

How do I go about doing this? - I've done some searching and looking at the objects at hand while debugging, but nothing seems to give me the SOAP xml.

I didnt post any of my code as my problem isnt a specific coding problem, but more of a "how do I do X.." issue.

Comment: Write a handler/interceptor to get the `SOAPMessage` object, with which you can do whatever you please

Comment: Yeah, I wrote a SoapHandler (which implements the SOAPHandler interface) and it seems like it can be done that way. :)